# Same cp model, nothing changed, but sometimes feasible sometimes infeasible

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

I have tried to reduce the problem size，but still have no idea why it did not work, could you help me with this problem?

I used BCCompare to find the difference between infeasible and feasible logs, it seems there is something wrong in presolve.

Search log with infeasible solution:

```
`Starting CP-SAT solver v9.2.9972
Setting number of workers to 16
Parameters: random_seed: 10 max_time_in_seconds: 20 log_search_progress: true num_search_workers: 16

Initial optimization model '':
#Variables: 81 (5 in objective)
  - 12 in [0,1]
  - 19 in [0,100000]
  - 48 in [614,100000]
  - 2 constants in {1} 
#kInterval: 728 (#enforced: 16)
#kLinMax: 12
#kLinear1: 24 (#enforced: 22)
#kLinear2: 53 (#enforced: 48)
#kLinear3: 10 (#enforced: 8)
#kLinearN: 4 (#terms: 18)
#kNoOverlap: 297 (#intervals: 594, #optional: 16, #variable_sizes: 8)

Starting presolve at 0.00s
[Probing] deterministic_time: 1.034e-05 (limit: 1) wall_time: 8.85e-05 (38/38)
[Probing]  - new fixed Boolean: 6 (10/38)
[Probing]  - new integer bounds: 4
[SAT presolve] num removable Booleans: 38 / 97
[SAT presolve] num trivial clauses: 16
[SAT presolve] [0s] clauses:2 literals:8 vars:8 one_side_vars:8 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[SAT presolve] [1.12e-05s] clauses:2 literals:8 vars:8 one_side_vars:8 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[SAT presolve] [1.97e-05s] clauses:2 literals:8 vars:8 one_side_vars:8 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[Probing] deterministic_time: 7.7e-06 (limit: 1) wall_time: 5.23e-05 (32/32)
[Probing] deterministic_time: 7.7e-06 (limit: 1) wall_time: 4.82e-05 (32/32)

Presolve summary:
  - 20 affine relations were detected.
  - 12 variable equivalence relations were detected.
  - rule 'affine: new relation' was applied 20 times.
  - rule 'deductions: 78 stored' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'deductions: reduced variable domain' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'dual: enforced equivalence' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'dual: reduced domain' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'duplicate: removed constraint' was applied 8 times.
  - rule 'interval: performed intervals must have a positive size' was applied 6408 times.
  - rule 'linear1: without enforcement' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: always true' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'linear: dual fixing' was applied 4 times.
  - rule 'linear: fixed or dup variables' was applied 30 times.
  - rule 'linear: negative clause' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: positive equal one' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: reduced variable domains' was applied 4 times.
  - rule 'linear: remapped using affine relations' was applied 15 times.
  - rule 'linear: simplified rhs' was applied 17 times.
  - rule 'linear: tightened into equality' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'no_overlap: split into disjoint components' was applied 289 times.
  - rule 'objective: variable not used elsewhere' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'presolve: 10 unused variables removed.' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'presolve: iteration' was applied 3 times.
  - rule 'setppc: removed dominated constraints' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'variables: add encoding constraint' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'variables: detect half reified value encoding' was applied 22 times.
  - rule 'variables: only used in encoding' was applied 8 times.

Presolved optimization model '':
#Variables: 59 (3 in objective)
  - 10 in [0,1]
  - 1 in [0,99172]
  - 1 in [595,99797]
  - 1 in [600,99797]
  - 44 in [614,100000]
  - 1 in [798,100000]
  - 1 in [803,100000]
#kExactlyOne: 2 (#literals: 8)
#kInterval: 728 (#enforced: 16)
#kLinMax: 12
#kLinear2: 41 (#enforced: 40)
#kNoOverlap: 8 (#intervals: 16, #optional: 16)

Preloading model.
#Bound   0.01s best:inf   next:[1195,794626] initial_domain
#Model   0.01s var:59/59 constraints:791/791

Starting Search at 0.01s with 16 workers and subsolvers: [ default_lp, fixed, reduced_costs, pseudo_costs, no_lp, max_lp, core, quick_restart, quick_restart_no_lp, lb_tree_search, probing, feasibility_pump, rnd_var_lns_default, rnd_cst_lns_default, graph_var_lns_default, graph_cst_lns_default, scheduling_time_window_lns_default, scheduling_random_lns_default, rins_lns_default, rens_lns_default ]
#1       0.01s best:1370  next:[1195,1369] default_lp fixed_bools:0/21
#2       0.01s best:1195  next:[1195,1194] default_lp fixed_bools:1/26
Absolute gap limit of 0.0001 reached.
#Done    0.01s default_lp
#Done    0.01s fixed

Sub-solver search statistics:
  'reduced_costs':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 75 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 123
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'pseudo_costs':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 75 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 123
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'max_lp':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 123 rows, 75 columns, 346 entries with magnitude in [2.577497e-02, 1.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 123
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'lb_tree_search':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 75 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 123
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)


Solutions found per subsolver:
  'default_lp': 2

Objective bounds found per subsolver:
  'initial_domain': 1

CpSolverResponse summary:
status: OPTIMAL
objective: 1195
best_bound: 1195
booleans: 10
conflicts: 0
branches: 20
propagations: 24
integer_propagations: 125
restarts: 20
lp_iterations: 0
walltime: 0.0289492
usertime: 0.0289493
deterministic_time: 3.30106e-05
gap_integral: 9.69852e-05

LOT_206 LOT_206,QTIME_105 600
LOT_275 LOT_275,QTIME_105 595

Starting CP-SAT solver v9.2.9972
Setting number of workers to 16
Parameters: random_seed: 10 max_time_in_seconds: 20 log_search_progress: true num_search_workers: 16

Initial optimization model '':
#Variables: 98 (19 in objective)
  - 12 in [0,1]
  - 36 in [0,100000]
  - 48 in [614,100000]
  - 2 constants in {1} 
#kInterval: 728 (#enforced: 16)
#kLinMax: 29
#kLinear1: 27 (#enforced: 22)
#kLinear2: 50 (#enforced: 48)
#kLinear3: 10 (#enforced: 8)
#kLinearN: 4 (#terms: 18)
#kNoOverlap: 297 (#intervals: 594, #optional: 16, #variable_sizes: 8)

Starting presolve at 0.00s
[Probing] deterministic_time: 4.07e-05 (limit: 1) wall_time: 0.0002267 (72/72)
[Probing]  - new fixed Boolean: 6 (8/72)
[Probing]  - new integer bounds: 3
[SAT presolve] num removable Booleans: 57 / 114
[SAT presolve] num trivial clauses: 16
[SAT presolve] [0s] clauses:2 literals:8 vars:8 one_side_vars:8 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[SAT presolve] [9.2e-06s] clauses:2 literals:8 vars:8 one_side_vars:8 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[SAT presolve] [1.85e-05s] clauses:2 literals:8 vars:8 one_side_vars:8 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[Probing] deterministic_time: 3.738e-05 (limit: 1) wall_time: 0.0001679 (66/66)
[Probing] deterministic_time: 3.738e-05 (limit: 1) wall_time: 0.0002094 (66/66)

Presolve summary:
  - 34 affine relations were detected.
  - 25 variable equivalence relations were detected.
  - rule 'affine: new relation' was applied 34 times.
  - rule 'deductions: 78 stored' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'deductions: reduced variable domain' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'dual: enforced equivalence' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'duplicate: removed constraint' was applied 8 times.
  - rule 'interval: performed intervals must have a positive size' was applied 6408 times.
  - rule 'lin_max: converted to equality' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'lin_max: target domain reduced' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'linear1: without enforcement' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: always true' was applied 17 times.
  - rule 'linear: dual fixing' was applied 4 times.
  - rule 'linear: empty' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: fixed or dup variables' was applied 45 times.
  - rule 'linear: negative clause' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: positive equal one' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: reduced variable domains' was applied 4 times.
  - rule 'linear: remapped using affine relations' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: simplified rhs' was applied 14 times.
  - rule 'no_overlap: split into disjoint components' was applied 289 times.
  - rule 'presolve: 15 unused variables removed.' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'presolve: iteration' was applied 3 times.
  - rule 'setppc: removed dominated constraints' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'variables: add encoding constraint' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'variables: detect half reified value encoding' was applied 34 times.
  - rule 'variables: only used in encoding' was applied 8 times.

Presolved optimization model '':
#Variables: 57 (3 in objective)
  - 10 in [0,1]
  - 44 in [614,100000]
  - 1 in [798,100000]
  - 2 in [803,100000]
#kExactlyOne: 2 (#literals: 8)
#kInterval: 728 (#enforced: 16)
#kLinMax: 13
#kLinear1: 12 (#enforced: 12)
#kLinear2: 28 (#enforced: 28)
#kNoOverlap: 8 (#intervals: 16, #optional: 16)

Preloading model.
#Bound   0.01s best:inf   next:[2404,300000] initial_domain
#Model   0.01s var:57/57 constraints:791/791

Starting Search at 0.01s with 16 workers and subsolvers: [ default_lp, fixed, reduced_costs, pseudo_costs, no_lp, max_lp, core, quick_restart, quick_restart_no_lp, lb_tree_search, probing, feasibility_pump, rnd_var_lns_default, rnd_cst_lns_default, graph_var_lns_default, graph_cst_lns_default, scheduling_time_window_lns_default, scheduling_random_lns_default, rins_lns_default, rens_lns_default ]
#Done    0.01s core

Sub-solver search statistics:
  'reduced_costs':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 75 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 118
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'pseudo_costs':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 75 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 118
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'max_lp':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 118 rows, 75 columns, 314 entries with magnitude in [6.344189e-03, 1.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 118
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'lb_tree_search':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 75 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 118
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)


Objective bounds found per subsolver:
  'initial_domain': 1

CpSolverResponse summary:
status: INFEASIBLE
objective: NA
best_bound: NA
booleans: 47
conflicts: 1
branches: 80
propagations: 220
integer_propagations: 494
restarts: 76
lp_iterations: 0
walltime: 0.0182442
usertime: 0.0182443
deterministic_time: 0.000130953
gap_integral: 0
`
```

Here is the search log with optimal solution:

```
`Starting CP-SAT solver v9.2.9972
Parameters: random_seed: 10 max_time_in_seconds: 20 log_search_progress: true num_search_workers: 16

Initial optimization model '':
#Variables: 81 (5 in objective)
  - 12 in [0,1]
  - 19 in [0,100000]
  - 48 in [614,100000]
  - 2 constants in {1} 
#kInterval: 728 (#enforced: 16)
#kLinMax: 12
#kLinear1: 24 (#enforced: 22)
#kLinear2: 53 (#enforced: 48)
#kLinear3: 10 (#enforced: 8)
#kLinearN: 4 (#terms: 18)
#kNoOverlap: 297 (#intervals: 594, #optional: 16, #variable_sizes: 8)

Starting presolve at 0.00s
[Probing] deterministic_time: 1.034e-05 (limit: 1) wall_time: 0.0001116 (38/38)
[Probing]  - new fixed Boolean: 6 (10/38)
[Probing]  - new integer bounds: 4
[SAT presolve] num removable Booleans: 38 / 97
[SAT presolve] num trivial clauses: 16
[SAT presolve] [0s] clauses:2 literals:8 vars:8 one_side_vars:8 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[SAT presolve] [2.7e-05s] clauses:2 literals:8 vars:8 one_side_vars:8 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[SAT presolve] [3.76e-05s] clauses:2 literals:8 vars:8 one_side_vars:8 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[Probing] deterministic_time: 7.7e-06 (limit: 1) wall_time: 7.29e-05 (32/32)
[Probing] deterministic_time: 7.7e-06 (limit: 1) wall_time: 5.91e-05 (32/32)

Presolve summary:
  - 20 affine relations were detected.
  - 12 variable equivalence relations were detected.
  - rule 'affine: new relation' was applied 20 times.
  - rule 'deductions: 78 stored' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'deductions: reduced variable domain' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'dual: enforced equivalence' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'dual: reduced domain' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'duplicate: removed constraint' was applied 8 times.
  - rule 'interval: performed intervals must have a positive size' was applied 6408 times.
  - rule 'linear1: without enforcement' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: always true' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'linear: dual fixing' was applied 4 times.
  - rule 'linear: fixed or dup variables' was applied 30 times.
  - rule 'linear: negative clause' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: positive equal one' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: reduced variable domains' was applied 4 times.
  - rule 'linear: remapped using affine relations' was applied 15 times.
  - rule 'linear: simplified rhs' was applied 17 times.
  - rule 'linear: tightened into equality' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'no_overlap: split into disjoint components' was applied 289 times.
  - rule 'objective: variable not used elsewhere' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'presolve: 10 unused variables removed.' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'presolve: iteration' was applied 3 times.
  - rule 'setppc: removed dominated constraints' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'variables: add encoding constraint' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'variables: detect half reified value encoding' was applied 22 times.
  - rule 'variables: only used in encoding' was applied 8 times.

Presolved optimization model '':
#Variables: 59 (3 in objective)
  - 10 in [0,1]
  - 1 in [0,99172]
  - 1 in [595,99797]
  - 1 in [600,99797]
  - 44 in [614,100000]
  - 1 in [798,100000]
  - 1 in [803,100000]
#kExactlyOne: 2 (#literals: 8)
#kInterval: 728 (#enforced: 16)
#kLinMax: 12
#kLinear2: 41 (#enforced: 40)
#kNoOverlap: 8 (#intervals: 16, #optional: 16)

Preloading model.
#Bound   0.01s best:inf   next:[1195,794626] initial_domain
#Model   0.01s var:59/59 constraints:791/791

Starting Search at 0.01s with 16 workers and subsolvers: [ default_lp, fixed, reduced_costs, pseudo_costs, no_lp, max_lp, core, quick_restart, quick_restart_no_lp, lb_tree_search, probing, feasibility_pump, rnd_var_lns_default, rnd_cst_lns_default, graph_var_lns_default, graph_cst_lns_default, scheduling_time_window_lns_default, scheduling_random_lns_default, rins_lns_default, rens_lns_default ]
#1       0.01s best:1370  next:[1195,1369] no_lp fixed_bools:0/21
#2       0.01s best:1195  next:[1195,1194] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/21
Absolute gap limit of 0.0001 reached.
#Done    0.01s quick_restart_no_lp

Sub-solver search statistics:
  'reduced_costs':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 5 rows, 75 columns, 17 entries with magnitude in [2.062941e-01, 1.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #OPTIMAL: 1
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 123
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'pseudo_costs':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 75 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 123
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'max_lp':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 123 rows, 75 columns, 346 entries with magnitude in [2.577497e-02, 1.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 123
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'lb_tree_search':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 75 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 123
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)


Solutions found per subsolver:
  'no_lp': 1
  'quick_restart_no_lp': 1

Objective bounds found per subsolver:
  'initial_domain': 1

CpSolverResponse summary:
status: OPTIMAL
objective: 1195
best_bound: 1195
booleans: 11
conflicts: 0
branches: 21
propagations: 27
integer_propagations: 128
restarts: 20
lp_iterations: 0
walltime: 0.021072
usertime: 0.0210721
deterministic_time: 3.77962e-05
gap_integral: 9.64092e-05

LOT_206 LOT_206,QTIME_105 600
LOT_275 LOT_275,QTIME_105 595

Starting CP-SAT solver v9.2.9972
Parameters: random_seed: 10 max_time_in_seconds: 20 log_search_progress: true num_search_workers: 16

Initial optimization model '':
#Variables: 98 (19 in objective)
  - 12 in [0,1]
  - 36 in [0,100000]
  - 48 in [614,100000]
  - 2 constants in {1} 
#kInterval: 728 (#enforced: 16)
#kLinMax: 29
#kLinear1: 27 (#enforced: 22)
#kLinear2: 50 (#enforced: 48)
#kLinear3: 10 (#enforced: 8)
#kLinearN: 4 (#terms: 18)
#kNoOverlap: 297 (#intervals: 594, #optional: 16, #variable_sizes: 8)

Starting presolve at 0.00s
[Probing] deterministic_time: 4.07e-05 (limit: 1) wall_time: 0.000192 (72/72)
[Probing]  - new fixed Boolean: 6 (8/72)
[Probing]  - new integer bounds: 3
[SAT presolve] num removable Booleans: 57 / 114
[SAT presolve] num trivial clauses: 16
[SAT presolve] [0s] clauses:2 literals:8 vars:8 one_side_vars:8 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[SAT presolve] [7.8e-06s] clauses:2 literals:8 vars:8 one_side_vars:8 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[SAT presolve] [1.73e-05s] clauses:2 literals:8 vars:8 one_side_vars:8 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[Probing] deterministic_time: 3.738e-05 (limit: 1) wall_time: 0.0001626 (66/66)
[Probing] deterministic_time: 3.738e-05 (limit: 1) wall_time: 0.0001704 (66/66)

Presolve summary:
  - 34 affine relations were detected.
  - 25 variable equivalence relations were detected.
  - rule 'affine: new relation' was applied 34 times.
  - rule 'deductions: 78 stored' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'deductions: reduced variable domain' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'dual: enforced equivalence' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'duplicate: removed constraint' was applied 8 times.
  - rule 'interval: performed intervals must have a positive size' was applied 6408 times.
  - rule 'lin_max: converted to equality' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'lin_max: target domain reduced' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'linear1: without enforcement' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: always true' was applied 17 times.
  - rule 'linear: dual fixing' was applied 4 times.
  - rule 'linear: empty' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: fixed or dup variables' was applied 45 times.
  - rule 'linear: negative clause' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: positive equal one' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: reduced variable domains' was applied 4 times.
  - rule 'linear: remapped using affine relations' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'linear: simplified rhs' was applied 14 times.
  - rule 'no_overlap: split into disjoint components' was applied 289 times.
  - rule 'presolve: 15 unused variables removed.' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'presolve: iteration' was applied 3 times.
  - rule 'setppc: removed dominated constraints' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'variables: add encoding constraint' was applied 16 times.
  - rule 'variables: detect half reified value encoding' was applied 34 times.
  - rule 'variables: only used in encoding' was applied 8 times.

Presolved optimization model '':
#Variables: 57 (3 in objective)
  - 10 in [0,1]
  - 44 in [614,100000]
  - 1 in [798,100000]
  - 2 in [803,100000]
#kExactlyOne: 2 (#literals: 8)
#kInterval: 728 (#enforced: 16)
#kLinMax: 13
#kLinear1: 12 (#enforced: 12)
#kLinear2: 28 (#enforced: 28)
#kNoOverlap: 8 (#intervals: 16, #optional: 16)

Preloading model.
#Bound   0.01s best:inf   next:[2404,300000] initial_domain
#Model   0.01s var:57/57 constraints:791/791

Starting Search at 0.01s with 16 workers and subsolvers: [ default_lp, fixed, reduced_costs, pseudo_costs, no_lp, max_lp, core, quick_restart, quick_restart_no_lp, lb_tree_search, probing, feasibility_pump, rnd_var_lns_default, rnd_cst_lns_default, graph_var_lns_default, graph_cst_lns_default, scheduling_time_window_lns_default, scheduling_random_lns_default, rins_lns_default, rens_lns_default ]
#1       0.01s best:2404  next:[2404,2403] fixed fixed_bools:8/55
Absolute gap limit of 0.0001 reached.
#Done    0.01s fixed

Sub-solver search statistics:
  'reduced_costs':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 75 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 118
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'pseudo_costs':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 75 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 118
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'max_lp':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 118 rows, 75 columns, 314 entries with magnitude in [6.344189e-03, 1.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 118
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'lb_tree_search':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 75 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 118
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)


Solutions found per subsolver:
  'fixed': 1

Objective bounds found per subsolver:
  'initial_domain': 1

CpSolverResponse summary:
status: OPTIMAL
objective: 2404
best_bound: 2404
booleans: 48
conflicts: 2
branches: 84
propagations: 250
integer_propagations: 408
restarts: 76
lp_iterations: 0
walltime: 0.0185324
usertime: 0.0185325
deterministic_time: 0.000126617
gap_integral: 6.60877e-05


Starting CP-SAT solver v9.2.9972
Parameters: random_seed: 10 max_time_in_seconds: 10 log_search_progress: true num_search_workers: 16

Initial optimization model '':
#Variables: 98 (2 in objective)
  - 12 in [0,1]
  - 36 in [0,100000]
  - 48 in [614,100000]
  - 2 constants in {1} 
#kInterval: 728 (#enforced: 16)
#kLinMax: 29
#kLinear1: 42 (#enforced: 22)
#kLinear2: 50 (#enforced: 48)
#kLinear3: 10 (#enforced: 8)
#kLinearN: 4 (#terms: 18)
#kNoOverlap: 297 (#intervals: 594, #optional: 16, #variable_sizes: 8)

Starting presolve at 0.00s
[Probing] deterministic_time: 0 (limit: 1) wall_time: 5.2e-06 (18/18)
[Probing] deterministic_time: 0 (limit: 1) wall_time: 3.4e-06 (18/18)
[Probing] deterministic_time: 0 (limit: 1) wall_time: 3.1e-06 (18/18)

Presolve summary:
  - 24 affine relations were detected.
  - 29 variable equivalence relations were detected.
  - rule 'affine: new relation' was applied 24 times.
  - rule 'false enforcement literal' was applied 54 times.
  - rule 'interval: performed intervals must have a positive size' was applied 6470 times.
  - rule 'lin_max: always satisfied' was applied 6 times.
  - rule 'lin_max: converted to equality' was applied 17 times.
  - rule 'lin_max: reduced expression domain.' was applied 10 times.
  - rule 'lin_max: removed exprs' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'lin_max: target domain reduced' was applied 10 times.
  - rule 'linear1: without enforcement' was applied 7 times.
  - rule 'linear: always true' was applied 18 times.
  - rule 'linear: empty' was applied 30 times.
  - rule 'linear: fixed or dup variables' was applied 78 times.
  - rule 'linear: reduced variable domains' was applied 65 times.
  - rule 'linear: remapped using affine relations' was applied 22 times.
  - rule 'linear: simplified rhs' was applied 13 times.
  - rule 'linear: singleton column' was applied 4 times.
  - rule 'no_overlap: no intervals' was applied 2 times.
  - rule 'no_overlap: no variable intervals' was applied 6 times.
  - rule 'no_overlap: removed absent intervals' was applied 8 times.
  - rule 'no_overlap: split into disjoint components' was applied 289 times.
  - rule 'presolve: 64 unused variables removed.' was applied 1 time.
  - rule 'presolve: iteration' was applied 3 times.
  - rule 'true enforcement literal' was applied 38 times.

Presolved optimization model '':
#Variables: 14 (0 in objective)
  - 14 in [614,100000]
#kInterval: 718
#kLinMax: 6

Preloading model.
#Bound   0.00s best:inf   next:[1601,1601] initial_domain
#Model   0.00s var:14/14 constraints:724/724 compo:4,4,3,3

Starting Search at 0.00s with 16 workers and subsolvers: [ default_lp, reduced_costs, pseudo_costs, no_lp, max_lp, quick_restart, quick_restart_no_lp, lb_tree_search, probing, feasibility_pump, rnd_var_lns_default, rnd_cst_lns_default, graph_var_lns_default, graph_cst_lns_default, rins_lns_default, rens_lns_default ]
#1       0.01s best:1601  next:[1601,1600] default_lp [hint] fixed_bools:0/8
Absolute gap limit of 0.0001 reached.
#Done    0.01s default_lp [hint]

Sub-solver search statistics:
  'reduced_costs':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 6 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 6
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 3 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 2
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 6 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 6
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 3 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 2
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)

  'pseudo_costs':
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 6 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 6
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 3 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 2
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 6 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 6
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)
     LP statistics:
       final dimension: 0 rows, 3 columns, 0 entries with magnitude in [0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00]
       total number of simplex iterations: 0
       num solves: 
         - #DUAL_FEASIBLE: 1
       managed constraints: 2
       total cuts added: 0 (out of 0 calls)


Solutions found per subsolver:
  'default_lp': 1

Objective bounds found per subsolver:
  'initial_domain': 1

CpSolverResponse summary:
status: OPTIMAL
objective: 1601
best_bound: 1601
booleans: 8
conflicts: 0
branches: 8
propagations: 0
integer_propagations: 15
restarts: 1
lp_iterations: 0
walltime: 0.0145568
usertime: 0.0145569
deterministic_time: 0
gap_integral: 0`
```

[BC Compare result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrw3H.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old version.

We have fixed many bugs since then. Please update to 9.8 and 9.9 when released this week.

Comment: Thanks! I will try new version to fix this problem.